# Ports will not open windows server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vps, port-forwarding

I recently Purchased a VPS that runs windows server 2012 on it and I cannot seem to open any ports.

I have gone into Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, and making a new inbound and outbound rule for the port, but when I check if the port is open via http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ it says it's closed

Cheers

Tom

Comment: Does the VPS have a network firewall, akin to a Security Group in AWS or an NSG in Azure?

Comment: Does the output of `netstat -an` show the the port as listening?

Comment: Well, can you call your provider? Support, you know. There is a chance there is another firewall in front and you just do not bother to read the documentation which would point you to a website where you could handle that.

Comment: @MassNerder Nope, doesn't show there

Comment: @TomTom I contacted the host, apparently the VPS controls it's own Ports through Firewall

Comment: Then nothing is listening on that port. Review your application configuration, make sure the app is running and configured to run on the correct port

Answer (score 1):

Since the output of `netstat -an` does not show a process listening on that port it means the application is not configured to run on that port or the application is not running. Check your application configuration, make sure it is configured to run on the specific port you want and make sure the application is running